# Indentation inside brackets and not beside closing bracket in emacs

Tags: c, emacs, indentation

I'm finally making the big jump, leaving Vim for Emacs, and I can say I'm pretty delighted already (not in term of speed for now... but that will catch up).

However, there is this thing I'm trying to figure out...

When I code a for loop in *C*, for example, and add an opening braces, this is what I get

[image: code1]

Then I expand braces by pressing `C-j` and this is where I end.

[image: code2]

The issue is, I'm used to end there (this is how my vim was configured)

[image: code3]

But I can't figure out how to do this... I'm just starting with emacs and lisp and seem overwhelmed already by that tiny thing. I've already mapped a chord so when I press `kk` I insert an empty line above the current line and indent it properly. So for now, what I do is `RET kk` but i'd like my return key to do that by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure where newlines are inserted with [`c-hanging-braces-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Hanging-Braces.html)

> **Hanging Braces**
>   To specify which kinds of braces you want auto-newlines put around, you set the style variable `c-hanging-braces-alist`.

E.g., to keep the brace on the same line as `for` and insert a newline after it

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(c-hanging-braces-alist (quote ((substatement-open . (after))))))
```

---

Another approach could be to use [Yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) and define an appropriate template

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: for
# --
for ($1; $2; $3) {
$0
}
```

Now you can enter <kbd>for</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> and Yasnippet will automatically insert

```
for (; ; ) {

}
```

and wait for you to insert the fields leaving the cursor between the braces when finished.

Comment: If you have a lot of time, there's also the [CC Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/) manual and http://www.emacswiki.org/, where you can find a lot more about emacs.